# Adding a new account to my Samsung phone

Tags: google-account, crashes

I wanted to change account on my phone so I removed it from Accounts (it was the only google account on my device).

Now when I try to add a new account the Settings application is closes itself (force closes?). I've tried clearing the cache of all Google related apps and signing in to Google and Chrome apps.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a third party app that's in your way. Therefore, try adding the account while in safe mode. Because while you're in safe mode, all third party apps are disable, so they can't make any trouble.

To go into safe mode, turn your phone off, and then turn it back on while holding down on the volume down button. When the phone turns on, it will say **safe mode** on the bottom left of your screen.

Now try adding the account while in safe mode. Go to settings → accounts → and account → Google....

Comment: Didn't work, the same happened.